# Error when switching .NET MAUI from debug to release

Tags: c#, android, .net, visual-studio, maui

when i try to build my MAUI application (.net7-android) i get the following warning:

```
Description MSB3073: The command 
""C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Android\android- 
sdk\platform-tools\adb" -s 
ZY22BL2K84 uninstall -k 
"de.rnd_games.thetavern"" exited 
with code 1.
```

After building the app in release Mode  und install it manually on my device (NOT deploying it) the app instantly crashes. But if i deploy it in debug mode to my mobile everything works fine.
Can anyone please help? Thank you

Comment: Has it come to your mind to deploy it in release? What happens then?

Comment: You need to publish your application to make sure it works on deployed machine.  Publish always uses the Release folder.  There are minor differences in the debug/release code that would prevent code from running on a deploy machine without publishing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps:

1.try to remove the bin and obj folders ,then uninstall the previous versions of the app from your device, and try again;

2.if the problem persist, try to set the `Linker behavior` to `Don't link` and try again;

3.try to disable `AOT`;

Comment: In my case uncheck AOT compilation helped me

Comment: Congrats. And thanks for your sharing.   :)

Comment: I am glad to help :)